# is affect both a passive and an active verb?

Tags: grammar

The following statement had me confused:

> "To date, we have not seen fraud on a scale that could have affected a different outcome in the election"

To me this is an active form of affect, that I haven't seen before. Normally I see "affect" used like:
"we have not seen fraud on a scale that could have affected the election" or
"we have not seen fraud on a scale that could affect the election"

Interestingly the original quote uses "effected" instead:

> "to date, we have not seen fraud on a scale that could have effected a different outcome in the election"
>
> [AP News: Disputing Trump, Barr says no widespread election fraud](https://apnews.com/article/barr-no-widespread-election-fraud-b1f1488796c9a98c4b1a9061a6c7f49d)

So what is right and wrong here?

Comment: Won't a dictionary solve this problem? [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/effect): "*effect* 1: to cause to come into being." That's the definition being used here. The problem is that for a large number of English dialects, these are homonyms and people don't distinguish between them (which is not really a disaster, since it's usually easy to tell the meaning from context).

Comment: This has nothing to do with active or passive.

Those two mean different things. Each is correct for saying what it says. The dictionary will tell you that *to effect* means to bring about or to realize, not to cause the way *to affect* means.